# Snow v02. Broken mesh when linking

Tags: mesh, rigging

[image]
I link "snow v02" character into my new file. when i save and reopen it, the mesh in the brow or cheek is broken.
I have been redownloaded "snow v02" character and these problems still happen.
How to fix it?

Comment: Which version of Blender are you using?

Comment: @Atkay now i use 3.1.2. 
Previously, i try with 3.1.0 & have same problems.